# Removing numbers.

Tags: python, strip

Im trying to remove numbers from a print statement, but when i do try, it doesn't. It actually adds extra lines that are unwanted.

```
p=open('test1.txt','r')
t=open('outChanger.txt','w')

counter=0
for l in p:
counter+=1
if counter%3==0:
    print((l.swapcase()*2),l.strip('2'))

t.close()
p.close()
```

I want it to look like this, but without the 2's.

tHE ANTS GO MARCHING 2 BY 2,

tHE ANTS GO MARCHING 2 BY 2,

(It  adds this with the .strip.) The ants go marching 2 by 2,

tO GET OUT OF THE RAIN, boom! boom! boom!

tO GET OUT OF THE RAIN, boom! boom! boom!

(and adds this as well)To get out of the rain, BOOM! BOOM! BOOM!

Comment: Can you provide the contents of the files?

Comment: Unrelated, but instead of maintaining a `counter` variable, just use `enumerate`

Comment: Indent your code properly

Comment: The ants go marching 2 by 2, hurrah, hurrah
The ants go marching 2 by 2, hurrah, hurrah
The ants go marching 2 by 2,
The little one stops to tie their shoe
And they all go marching down to the ground
To get out of the rain, BOOM! BOOM! BOOM!
 @RushyPanchal

Comment: `strip` only removes characters at the end of the string, but your string seems to end with `,`, not `2`

Comment: @tobias_k im still learning pythom and we havent learned that yet. so we're not allowed to use that. Thank you though

Comment: Are there any other basic Python language features and builtin functions you are not allowed to use, so we can avoid them in our answers?

Comment: @tobias_k I want to say its just enumerate. I'm not to sure though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might want to call the `.strip()` on the string that you print the first, not print it again:

```
print(l.swapcase().strip()*2)
```

By chaining methods like this, you will strip `"2"` from the string and then print the stripped string twice. If you don't want to strip the `"2"` from the middle, call the `.strip()` method after you multiply the string:

```
print((l.swapcase()*2).strip())
```

**EDIT**: Since your string does not end with `"2"`, the `.strip()` won't work as it only removes from edges. To remove all `"2"`s from a string, call the `.replace()` method on it like that:

```
print(l.swapcase().replace("2", "")*2)
```

This will replace all `"2"`s with an empty string, so it will pretty much remove them.

Comment: It still wont remove the 2's from the string.

Comment: @Julian Well, that's because the strip is not what you want. See, I have trouble understanding your question, but I'll try to. So you want to remove all "2"s, right?

Comment: Yeah, that is what i need help with.

Comment: @Julian Check out the edit

Comment: Ohh, okay, I would have never thought of that one. Thank you!